# How can I find the value of the unknown X using any algebraic method? Not numerical methods and programming.

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, exponential-sum

$$72^x+7^x=80$$

The only clue that I have is that using limits is possible to find the unknown number (L'Hôpital's Rule)... but anyway, if you use other method, please let me know and I will appreciate it.

Comment: Please, use MathJax

Comment: Wolfram specifies the exact form as "x = root of 7^x + 72^x - 80 near x = 1.00309". That is, the exact form of the solution is "plug this into a computer".

Comment: How exactly does L'Hôpital's rule tell you it is possible to find the solution algebraically?

Answer (score 3):

There is a unique real solution $x$, but it cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions. Of course you can use numerical methods to approximate the value of $x$, and it should be clear that $x$ is very slightly larger than $1$. With the help of a computer I quickly found that
$$x\approx1.0030899874071590958.$$

Comment: Specifically, it is around $1.003$

Comment: Do you want to say that you didn't do Newton's method in your head? :D

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Actually I did, I just didn't want to embarass others that would need the help of a computer to do so ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain *approximations* of the solution working around $x=1$ and using Taylor expansions to $O\big((x-1)^{n+1}\big)$ of
$$y=72^x+7^x-80$$ For the lowest case
$$y=-1+(x-1) (7 \log (7)+72 \log (72))+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ Now, using [series reversion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html)
$$x=1+\frac{y+1}{7 \log (7)+72 \log (72)}+O\left((y+1)^2\right)$$ and make $y=0$.

It is sure that the expressions become very messy when we increase $n$.

As a function of $n$, the numerical value of the *approximation* would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 &     \color{blue}{1.003}110020086640054432582 \\
 2 &     \color{blue}{1.003089}815152514185756329 \\
 3 &     \color{blue}{1.00308998}9068733934362861 \\
 4 &     \color{blue}{1.003089987}390094948474687 \\
 5 &     \color{blue}{1.003089987407}341396343243 \\
 6 &     \color{blue}{1.00308998740715}7094728794 \\
 7 &     \color{blue}{1.003089987407159}118243290 \\
 8 &     \color{blue}{1.003089987407159095}583690 \\
 9 &     \color{blue}{1.0030899874071590958}41276 \\
 10 &    \color{blue}{1.0030899874071590958383}13 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty & \color{blue}{1.003089987407159095838347}
\end{array}
\right)$$